# Lagrange Mean Value theorem

Tags: calculus

In case I've an interval for which I can apply Lagrange's MVT, does it hold for every c in the open interval? Meaning can I get any $f'$ value for any $c\in(a,b)$ by some other $x's$ in the interval?

Naively, it's seems correct, but I wonder about the case in which $f'$ is a non-continuous function.

Edit: I'm sure it's incorrect, but can't explain why.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but if $f(x)=x^3$ on $[-1,1]$, then $f'(0)=0$, but $(f(x)-f(y))/(x-y)\ne0$ for any $x\ne y$ with both $x$ and $y$ in $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! it requires a kind of "rescue" of the Robust LMVT.

Take $f(x)=x^{5/3}, x \in [-1,1]$, this function is both continuos and differentiable at $x=0$ but $f'(x)$ is not continuos at this point. Alternatively, $f'(x)$ is not next differentiable or $f(x)$ is not second differentiable at $x=0$.

So By LMVT there exists a point $x=c \in (-1,1)$ where $$\frac{f(1)-f(-1)}{1--1}=1=f'(c)=\frac{5}{3}c^{2/3} \implies c=(3/5)^{3/2}=0.4647 \in (-1,1)$$

**So all is well!**